# How to calculate drifting weights in a portfolio?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, finance

I'm finding the best efficient way to calculate drifting weights of a financial portfolio. I have a dataframe of returns of 4 assets:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'M_A7': [1, 1.006064, 1.006064, 1.010850204, 1.001120966, 0.996537736],
    'M_LD': [1, 1.008019, 1.007724061, 0.995000025, 0.993892509,0.99160124],
    'PEBUY Index': [1, 1.000923016, 1.000922165, 1.000921316, 1.000920468,1.000919621],
    'LEGATRUU Index': [1, 1, 0.99185916, 1.003503846, 1.008849898, 0.995664836]}

df_rets = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2016-12-31 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-02 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-03 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-04 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-05 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-06 00:00:00'])
```

Then I have an array of the weights of the 4 assets:

```
weights = np.array([0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
```

I want to compute the drifting weights (e.g., the subsequent weights are based on the return of the day) in order to obtain the desired dataframe.

```
weights_result= {'M_A7': [0.400000, 0.402426, 0.406792, 0.407248, 0.405838, 0.403564],
    'M_LD': [0.200000, 0.201604, 0.203161, 0.202145, 0.200911, 0.199223],
    'PEBUY Index': [0.200000, 0.200185, 0.200369, 0.200554, 0.200738, 0.200923],
    'LEGATRUU Index': [0.200000, 0.200000, 0.198372, 0.199067, 0.200829, 0.199958]}

df_weights_results = pd.DataFrame(weights_result, index=['2016-12-31 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-02 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-03 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-04 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-05 00:00:00',
                                '2017-01-06 00:00:00'])
```

I have tried various options like shift() or multiply() but I failed